# vscode not able to connect to docker image in macbook pro m1

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, x86, ubuntu-22.04, macbookpro

I have a ubuntu/amd64 architecture installed on my docker application which is running , so i want to connect that to my visual studio code . On my vscode i have installed the extension dev-container as well as docker . Trying to  connect to the  docker image through remote explorer and selecting one of the of attach it just keeps loading and noting really happens .
How can i solve this ?[![enter image description here][image][image][image]
System is macbook pro m1

i tried the approach as suggested by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8gUtN5j4QnY .